# Switching Django languages with flags and urls

Tags: django, internationalization

I am currently having a language switcher in Django based on flags, but where the URL for all languages are the same.

I would now like to change the language switcher so that selecting a flag also redirects the user to a URL prefix (like /en, /es, /fr, etc.) so I easily can send the page in different default languages to different users. Linking to the URL prefix works fine, but how do I easiest redirect the users there when they select flags in the code below?

```
<div class="navbar-btns ml-3">
 <div class="navbar-btns-inner">
   <div id="language-switcher" class="navbar-btn collapsed">
     <form action="{% url 'set_language' %}" method="post">
         {% csrf_token %}
         <input name="next" type="hidden" value="/" />
         <select name="language" onchange="this.form.submit()">
             {% for language in request|get_language_info_list_ex %}
                 <option value="{{ language.code }}" {% if language.is_current %} selected="selected"{% endif %}>
                     <span class="flag">{{ language.flag }}</span>
                     {# {{ language.code }} #}
                 </option>
             {% endfor %}
         </select>
     </form>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On my page I use a simple view and some regex to redirect the users back to the page they was on.

Here is my view

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from yourapp.utils.translation import get_locale_url

def set_language(request, language_code=None):
    url = request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER', settings.BASE_URL)
    url = get_locale_url(url, language_code)

    return HttpResponseRedirect(url)
```

and my utils.translation.py

```
import re
from django.conf import settings
from django.utils.translation import get_language

def get_locale_url(url, language_code):
    pattern = r'^(?:/)|^#$|(?:(?:https?://)?(?:yoursubdomain\.)?domain\.com/?(?:(?:sma|en)?/?)?)'
    if settings.USE_I18N:
        if any(language_code in language for language in settings.LANGUAGES):
            if re.match(pattern, url, flags=re.I):
                split_url = re.split(pattern, url, flags=re.I)
                if language_code == "nb":
                    url = settings.BASE_URL + "/" + split_url[len(split_url)-1]

                else:
                    url = settings.BASE_URL + "/" + language_code + "/" + split_url[len(split_url)-1]

    return url
```

Change *yoursubdomain* (usually www) and *yourdomain* to work with your own site. You also neeed to add the language codes you have activated to your regex pattern. I use *sma* and *en* so I've written (sma|en).

It ain't the prettiest solution, but it works.

Comment: Thanks! I had a go at it but I think I just had set my environment set up a bit different than yours - like you functional approach to things.

Ended up basing my solution on this:
https://brainstorm.it/snippets/django-language-switching/
But including some manual language switching. Even less pretty, but it worked! :)